# How to assign values already stored in fixed memory to a cimg object

Tags: c++, cimg

I am using the Cimg lib to do the image processing work. I have the pointer of an array returned by GPU, and I want to the Cimg object to take the value of the array directly. Now, I am using the for loops to do the work, but it is not very efficient.

The sample codes I am using now is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(){
    char pause;
    int width=3; int height=3;//Dimension of the Cimg matrix
    int size = width * height * sizeof(int); // number of bytes in total in arrays
    int *ptr = (int*) malloc(size);

    //Assign the array some example value; 
    for (int m=0;m<width*height;m++){
        *(ptr+m)=m;
    }

    CImg<int> img(width,height,1,1);

    //This is how I assign the value of the array to the Cimg object
    for (int i=0;i<width;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<height;j++)
        {
            img.atXY(i,j)=*(ptr+j*width+i);
        }

        img.save_bmp("img.bmp");
        cout<<"Pause:";
        cin>>pause;
    }
}
```

I tired this code, but it does not work:

```
img.begin()=ptr;
```

Anyone can help me to eliminate the for loops and improve the speed? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something as simple as :

```
img._data = ptr;
```

But beware, the ordering of values in the pixel buffer may be different from what you have in the input buffer, that could result in a strange looking image.

Comment: do you mean I can do img.data()=ptr? However, the codes cannot proceed as it indicates the img.data() is a constant pointer

Comment: no, `data()` is a method of the class CImg<T> that basically returns the field `CImg<T>::_data`. But you can modify `_data` directly if you wish (a bit hacky but this should work). Also take care to set `_data`to 0 before the object destruction, or the destructor will try to deallocate your newly set `_data` pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Now there is constructor that can use pointer as internal storage.

ex.

```
cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> img(ptr, 640, 480, 1, 3, true);
```

It's important to set last parameter to `true` as it's indicate that the pointer `ptr` should be used as internal storage instead of copying values from pointer.

more info here:

http://cimg.eu/reference/structcimg__library_1_1CImg.html#a24f3b43daa4444b94a973c2c3fff82c5

Answer (score 0):

Finally I decide to switch to opencv. In this way, the pointer can be easily assigned to the image mat and then be stored in an image.

I am still searching for the solution of cimg. It seems a bit strange to me that the cimg's pointer cannot be modified.

Answer (score 0):

from https://devolio.net/fish2000/cimg-fltkhpp/ :

```
/* Generates a w*h*4 CImg<uchar> image from the given rgb data. */
static inline cimg_library::CImg<uchar> cimg_from_rgba(
    uchar const* rgb,
    const uint dimw, const uint dimh
)
{
    cimg_library::CImg<uchar> res(dimw,dimh,1,4);

    uchar *pR = res.data(0,0,0,0),
          *pG = res.data(0,0,0,1),
          *pB = res.data(0,0,0,2),
          *pA = res.data(0,0,0,3);

    const uchar *ptrs   = rgb;

    for ( uint off = dimw*dimh; off>0; --off )
    {
        *(pR++) = (uchar)*(ptrs++);
        *(pG++) = (uchar)*(ptrs++);
        *(pB++) = (uchar)*(ptrs++);
        *(pA++) = (uchar)*(ptrs++);
    }

    return res;
}
```